# Visual studio - prevent linking of static library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

I am creating a static library in Visual Studio 2010. This library will be statically linked with another of my applications to produce the .exe. The thing is that I want my .exe to be statically linked against C adn C++ library (don't want dependency on msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll). But what ever I do I can't get it working.

If I link my static library with static C and C++ libs then I can't compile the .exe - Linker complains about "already defined symbols".

If I link my static library with C and C++ DLL then my .exe ends up having dependency on msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll.

How do I tell VS to link my static library with static C and C++ libs only when it's being linked in my .exe?

EDIT

Here are a fre linker errors when both static lib and .exe user /MT (i.e. static linking of runtime library):

```
1>msvcrt.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in re2_release.lib(regexp.obj)
1>msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char *,__int64)" (?setbuf@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEPAV12@PAD_J@Z) already defined in re2_release.lib(regexp.obj)
1>msvcrt.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtoul already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strtol.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

If I set /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT then errors from mscvrt.lib disappear, but msvcprt.lib errors remain.

Comment: Your EXE project settings must match the library project settings.

Comment: Doing so gives me "already defined" errors from linker. Both static library and .exe use Static C runtime linking, and most of the other settings are the same.

Comment: Please don't make us guess at the linker error messages.  Post the first couple of them.

Comment: Some module is not using static linking of the runtime library, because your linker errors show "msvcrt.lib" which is the import library for the DLL version.  Look more carefully through your project settings, and any other libraries you link to, making sure EVERYTHING is using /MT.

Comment: @librik you should have made a answer of your comment. I had the same probleme as the OP. Following your suggestion, I checked all my projects setting, and the main executable was using /MD while the libraries were using /MT.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and libriks solution solved it. I will quote him here for those who skips reading the comments:

> Some module is not using static linking of the runtime library, because your linker errors >show "msvcrt.lib" which is the import library for the DLL version. Look more carefully >through your project settings, and any other libraries you link to, making sure EVERYTHING is >using /MT.